# Touch ID Login and getting user Id from API

Tags: iphone, touch-id

In my app, there are two type of login. Login with email and password AND login with touch ID. Is it possible to login with touch ID and getting user ID from API..

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can login in either of the both ways .

1. Before you show the user login view controller , create a controller with a name authentication view controller and import local authentication framework and in the view will appear method write the code that is provided in the apple documentation for using touch id in the application.
2. Alternatively, you can also login with username and password when the ios device detects iOS 6,7 as touch id is supported from iOS 8 and the touch id has fall back mechanism which will also help in the same if user logs in with his username and password.